# How to use declared variable in included page?

Tags: jsp, variables, el, jspinclude

**on header include file:**

```
<head>
    <title>${pageTitle}</title>
</head>
```

**test page:**

```
<% String pageTitle = "Test Title"; %>

<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />
```

I am trying to declare the page title on the test page and use the value of that variable in the `title` tag of my header include. This doesn't seem to be working.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test.jsp

```
<% String pageTitle = "Test Title"; %>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="<%=pageTitle%>"/>
</jsp:include>
```

### header.jsp

To get the passing value you need to use `param` EL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>${param.pageTitle}</title>
               <!--Need to use param EL-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by

```
    <jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp">
       <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="value-here"/>
    </jsp:include>
```